# How to get linear descent random distribution?

Tags: python, random

Curently in django I implement showing person on main page randomly.
But now I need to show persons regarding their importance (which is number).
For example:
Name|Sortkey
John| 5
Tom | 8

John have to be shown more often linearly.

```
person_number = random.randrange(Person.objects.count())
context = { 'person': Person.objects.all()[person_number], }
```

I tried random.expovariate but It makes first person are too often.
So which function from random library I need to use?

UPD:
Basicly as randrange(10) gives [6,2,8,6,4,1,9,5,3,0,]
I need algorithm which gives something [1,7,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,0] 
1 - most often (3 times), 2 -less (2 times) ..etc

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you mean a weighted random choice. Basically you need to:

1. Create the list with the accumulative sum of weights.
2. Choose a random value [0, sum_of_weights-1]
3. Find the index in which the random value fell.

In Python terms, with a functional approach (*ireduce* = *scanl* = *partial_sum* = ...), it could look:

```
import operator
import bisect
import random

def ireduce(f, state, it):
    """Accumulative reduce. ireduce(operator.sum, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4]) -> 1, 3, 6, 10."""
    for x in it:
        state = f(state, x)
        yield state

people = [
  {"name": "Iain David", "weight": 1}, 
  {"name": "John Martyn", "weight": 2},
]
weights = (person["weight"] for person in people)  
accumulated_weights = list(ireduce(operator.add, 0, weights))
random_value = random.randrange(accumulated_weights[-1])
index = bisect.bisect_right(accumulated_weights, random_value)
random_person = people[index]["name"] 
# "Iain David" (p=1/3), "John Martyn" (p=2/3)
```

Comment: Elegant solution.  You will need a good understanding of iterators —- but that is worth the power they offer in my opinion.